# How to skip missing chunks in android when playing video?

Tags: android, media-player

I'm writing an android app that accepts an `HLS` and shows via `VideoView`. But sometimes there are missing chunks in the stream, and my player crashes. Here's how I'm trying to fix it.

```
player.setOnErrorListener(playerErrorHandler);

private class PlayerErrorHandler implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {

    private boolean handledError = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        if (!handledError) {
            if (!isOnline()) {
                finish();
            }
            //if we're here then we have a missing chunk
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
            mp.seekTo(currentPosition + 10);

        } else {
            handledError = false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}



private boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

So i just check on error if there's nothing wrong with my connection, and if erevything's ok, it means i have a missing chunk in my stream. But the problem is, my forwarding doesn't work and it keeps throwing an error continuously. How do I forward like 10 seconds? Or maybe better, is there a way to tell the mediaplayer to automatically skip missing chunks and continue playing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the right way through trials and errors. Here's how i skip the missing chunks

changed these lines

```
 int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
 mp.seekTo(currentPosition + 10);
```

to these

```
 int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();

 player.setVideoPath(streamUrl);
 player.seekTo(currentPosition + 5000);
 player.start();
```